# Why Earth's magnetism changes rapidly recently?

Tags: geomagnetism

The magnetic north pole is wandering near Canadian coast. The rate of pole wandering increased recently. Which factors causing these?

Comment: No-one knows. The generation of the Earth's magnetic field is not well understood.

Comment: Earth Science SE might be a good place to search/ask.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth's magnetic field is generated by the motion of liquid iron alloys in the core. According to an [article in Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-00007-1), one hypothesis for the recent rapid motion of magnetic north has to do with two patches of magnetic field at the outer surface of the core, one underneath Canada and one underneath Siberia. A high-speed jet of liquid iron underneath Canada is weakening that patch, so it's "losing a tug-of-war with Siberia."